# C#, ASP.NET MVC: Multiple image upload and uploaded images all remain the same problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to upload multiple images, I managed to upload as many images as I wanted. My only problem is that all the images I chose duplicate by copying the first one. I could not find the error in my codes.

My `UploadImage` method:

```
public static string UploadImage(string serverPath, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
        Guid uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid(); 
        serverPath = serverPath.Replace("~", string.Empty);
        string filePath;

        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in files)
        {
            if (files != null && item.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(item.FileName);
                string fileName = $"{uniqueName}{extension}";

                if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || extension.ToLower() == ".gif" || extension.ToLower() == ".png" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
                {
                    if (File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(serverPath + fileName))) 
                    {
                        return "Already exists from same file";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(serverPath),fileName);
                        item.SaveAs(filePath);
                        return serverPath+fileName;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Not the selected picture.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "No File Selected";
            }    
    }

    return "";
}
```

This is the `ImageController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TestClass model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in files)
        {
            model.ImagePath = ImageUploader.UploadImage("~/Images/", files) ;
            db.TestClass.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View();
}
```

and the `ImageClass`:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

and the view `Index.cshtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Image",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
<div>
     Name
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name)
</div>
<div>
    <input multiple type="file" name="files" value="Browse" />
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SOLVED**

I realized that the reason that the photos I tried to upload were uploaded as the same photo all the time was because the index number was always reset.

*As a solution:* I removed the foreach loop from the ImageUploader static method and defined an int type variable to the static class, and each time the foreach loop in ImageController runs, it will necessarily run on the static method and will increment once each time. When we want to upload an image again, we return it to zero when the process is finished so that the index number does not remain the same. This solution can be used when we both upload multiple photos and save data to the database. If we only want to upload multiple photos, a foreach loop should be used.

```
public static class ImageUploader
{
    internal static int indexer;


public static string UploadImage(string serverPath, List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        serverPath = serverPath.Replace("~", string.Empty);
        if (files != null || files[indexer].ContentLength < 0)
        {
            Guid uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid();
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[indexer].FileName);
            string fileName = $"{uniqueName}{extension}";
            if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || extension.ToLower() == ".gif" || extension.ToLower() == ".png" || extension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
            {
                if (File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(serverPath + fileName))) 
                {
                    return "Already Exists From Same File";
                }
                else
                {
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(serverPath),fileName);
                    files[indexer].SaveAs(filePath);
                    indexer++;
                if (indexer == files.Count)
                {
                    indexer = 0;
                }
                return serverPath + fileName;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Not the selected picture.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "No File Selected";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem  is that you just once generate a uniquename and use it for all of them.
you should put this line :

```
 Guid uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid();
```

in you `for` loop, like this :

```
 foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in files)
    {
        if (files != null && item.ContentLength > 0)
        {
             Guid uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid(); 
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(item.FileName);
            string fileName = $"{uniqueName}{extension}";
           // the rest of your code
}
```

and also there are some more things to fix
1- in you action method, you upload all files but your `UploadImage` method just returns a string, so `ImagePath` for all of them are equal.
you can rewrite it like below:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in files)
    {
        var  fileObj = new TestClass();
        fileObj.ImagePath = ImageUploader.UploadImage("~/Images/", files) ;
        db.TestClass.Add(fileObj);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: replacing the code did not help and also this code works the way I want.

When you add it to the database, the name changes, but the file extension remains with the extension of the first selected file and all images remain the same.

Comment: Have you chnage `Guid uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid();` in the `for` loop?

Comment: Should I also open a `for` loop inside the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, but writing these codes didn't solve my problem.
Let me explain the problem by giving an example;
For example, I select four pictures and when I click the save button, it adds to the database with the new Guid name, but the file extension of the first selected photo remains in the memory. Four pictures are added to the images folder, but the images are all the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmtiE.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NKxd.jpg)